# symfony2, How to install only new bundles added to deps file?

Tags: php, symfony, bundle

In symfony2 project `php bin/vendors install`, re-installs all bundles in `deps` file. Each time I add a bundle to `deps` file I have to wait for a long time.

Is there any other way to install/update only new added ones without re-installing everything?

Comment: I found the answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9023785/symfony2-updating-just-one-vendor-bundle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
php bin/vendors update
```

is correct. You can set a version on your debs file.

```
[twig]
    git=http://github.com/fabpot/Twig.git
    version=v1.8.2
```

The version is related to a "Git Tag" you can go to the vendor folder and check witch versions or git Tags are available:

```
git tag
```

Then you set your bundle to the specified version and he update the bundle only to this version and don't install a newer version.

Answer (score 1):

No, this is not supported by the `vendors` script. Since it was meant to be just as a stub until [Composer](http://getcomposer.org/) is released, no one bothers to make it a super optimized script.

BTW, it doesn't actually *reinstall* all the bundles on each run, but just clones new repos on the first run and then pulls them on consecutive runs.

Comment: I now use `php bin/vendors update` which is more faster. It only updates the installed one and installs the new added ones in `deps` file.

Comment: don't use update, it will update your deps to latest changes in master branches, ignoring deps.lock. Unless you actually want bleeding edge code.

Answer (score 0):

Comment unwanted bundles using "#"

For example :

```
#[symfony]
#    git=http://github.com/symfony/symfony.git
#    version=v2.0.21
#
#[twig]
#    git=http://github.com/fabpot/Twig.git
#    version=v1.10.3
#
#[monolog]
#    git=http://github.com/Seldaek/monolog.git
#    version=1.2.1
```

and execute

php bin/vendors install

or

php bin/vendors install --reinstall